# What javafx components for making Banner *Designing*

Tags: javafx, javafx-8, javafx-2

I am designing my javafx application and I need something like a Rectangle (Banner) that I can manipulate ***Changing Color*** and put something inside of it e.g Label/Image/Button/ etc. I tried **HBOX** but I want something like **Anchor Pane** that is whenever I drag something It'll put exactly.

Comment: Will users be dragging elements in this pane, or do you as a developer wish to create it by dragging elements? If it's the latter, you should try using Scene Builder.

Comment: You also might want to check out Canvas, if this is for drawing and adding shapes. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/canvas/Canvas.html

Comment: Only developer can drag intoo it. and user can edit the details inside of it..

Comment: So use an `AnchorPane`? Or a plain `Pane`?